# Firefox - launch applications from bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox

I want to create a folder on the bookmark toolbar and inside this folder i want to group by categories bookmarks links to installed applications on my hard disk and i want to be able to open the application when i click on the bookmark name, the same way i open bookmarked pages. But when i create a bookmark for .exe file and click on the bookmark it ask me if i want to save the file.

How can i make Firefox open the .exe file instead and launch the application?

Comment: You want to launch a (already installed) app from the web browser's bookmark bar?

Comment: Yes, installed application.

Comment: Nope, you can't really do this without scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension, that will call ShellExecute function. 
see [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes)

or to use exsiting

> [external-application-button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/external-application-button/)